# add legend to numpy array in matplot lib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am plotting 2D numpy arrays using

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([[2,2.2,3],[1,5,1]])
plt.plot(x,y.T[:,:])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I want a legend that tells which line belongs to which row. Of course, I realize I can't give it meaningful names, but I need some sort of unique label for the line without running through loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import uuid

x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([[2,2.2,3],[1,5,1]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lines = ax.plot(x,y.T[:,:])
ax.legend(lines, [str(uuid.uuid4())[:6] for j in range(len(lines))])


plt.show()
```

[image: example output]

(This is off of  the current mpl master branch with a preview of the 2.0 default styles)

Comment: The OP asked for unique labels, so those labels are guaranteed to be unique ;)

Comment: ued `[ j+1 for j in range(len(lines))]` which is unique enough. Thank you